# I'm getting error messages when trying to alter tables foreign keys. I did 2 fine but 2 won't work

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Have made tables and trying to alter to make foreign keys. Getting this error message:

> Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'ScriptID' and referenced column
> 'scriptID' in foreign key constraint 'FK_scriptID' are incompatible.

Also getting this error message:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
> constraint fails (`hpbooks2`.`#sql-152_b`, CONSTRAINT
> `FK_translatorID` FOREIGN KEY (`TranslatorID`) REFERENCES `translator`
> (`ID`))

Here is my code:

```
create database hpbooks2;

use hpbooks2;
CREATE TABLE Books 
(
    BookID  INT primary key,
    BookNo  INT,
    LanguageID  INT,
    ScriptID    VARCHAR(512),
    Category    VARCHAR(512),
    Authorised  VARCHAR(512),
    TranslatorID    INT,
    Title   VARCHAR(512)
);
CREATE TABLE Script 
(
    Script  VARCHAR(512),
    ScriptID    INT primary key
);
CREATE TABLE Translator 
(
    Translator  VARCHAR(512),
    ID  INT primary key
);
CREATE TABLE Language 
(
    Language    VARCHAR(512),
    LanguageID  INT primary key
);
CREATE TABLE Category 
(
    Category    VARCHAR(512) primary key,
    Description VARCHAR(512)
);
use hpbooks2;
alter table books
add constraint FK_translatorID foreign key (translatorID) references Translator(ID);
use hpbooks2;
alter table books
add constraint FK_scriptID foreign key (ScriptID) references Script(scriptID);
```

Comment: The first error message tells you that your ScriptID columns have inconsistent data types. VARCHAR(512) seems like an odd choice for an ID column.

Comment: If you'd modify a key referenced elsewhere as foreign key data in the referencing table gets inconsistent! You'd first need to change the referencing key to pointing to somewhere else, possibly null, if allowed, then modify referenced key, then set the reference again – *but* you should rather define your column as `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. Still agree with @jarlh, strings as id is a pretty bad choice. Better: Introduce a new numerical key for the any table that you won't ever change any more. Then you are free to modify the names as often as you want, and joins get cheaper additionally...

Comment: You have already numerical keys for script, language and translator, by the way. Why not for category as well?

Comment: thanks. I've fixed the scriptID one. I don't understand what you mean to fix the translatorID one though

Comment: The category is a 2 letter code so I didn't bother changing to a number

Comment: If it's a two letter code, then why `varchar(512)`? `char(2)` should be just as fine then. But obviously this brought you into trouble anyway ;)

Comment: To change (assuming it's a one-time change, otherwise consider cascading, see above): You could duplicate the row (entry) introducing the fixed id, update the referencing table to that new id and finally delete the old obsolete row.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first message :

> Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'ScriptID' and referenced column
> 'scriptID' in foreign key constraint 'FK_scriptID' are incompatible.

As it is said, columns type are incompatible :
In Books ScriptID is VARCHAR(512) whereas in Script, it is an INT.
Maybe you should modify your "CREATE TABLE Books" statement to use "ScriptID INT", instead of "ScriptID VARCHAR(512)".

For the second error message :

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
> constraint fails (`hpbooks2`.`#sql-152_b`, CONSTRAINT
> `FK_translatorID` FOREIGN KEY (`TranslatorID`) REFERENCES `translator`
> (`ID`))

It says that you have a row in Books for which you cannot check the integrity constraint you're trying to put on the Books table. You certainly have a Book in table Books, that have a translatorID that does not exists in table Translator.